# Showing price per unit for Woocommerce variations

Tags: woocommerce

I currently have products with a number of variations.
Each variation is a different number of cubic meters. For instance, from the variation drop down menu, one can choose:

```
1 m3
2 m3
...
```

Each variation has a price that becomes cheaper per unit when more units are purchased.
What I want to have is that the variation drop down menu looks as follows:

```
1 m3 (299 / m3)
2 m3 (289 / m3)
...
```

I have been looking in many of the Woocommerce template files but have not been able to track down exactly where the options are output.